# SQLite android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column android application

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am having an issue with my database that I can't figure out.  I'm getting an android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column. I'm trying to link two tables together, but I'm not using a foreign key.  Here is my database, datasource and the activity that is generating the error:

Database:

```
package com.mikero.termtracker;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Constants for DB
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "termtracker";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;



    //Constants for terms table

    public static final String KEY_ID = "termId";
    public static final String TERMS_TABLE = "terms";
    public static final String NAME_OF_TERM = "termsName";
    public static final String TERM_START_DATE = "termStartDate";
    public static final String TERM_END_DATE = "termEndDate";

    //Constants for courses table

    public static final String COURSE_TABLE = "course";
    public static final String COURSE_ID = "courseId";
    public static final String COURSE_NAME = "courseName";
    public static final String COURSE_START = "courseStart";
    public static final String COURSE_END = "courseEnd";
    public static final String COURSE_STATUS = "courseStatus";
    public static final String COURSE_MENTOR = "courseMentor";

    //constants for assessment table

    //constants for notes table

    //Create terms table
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TERMS = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TERMS_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + NAME_OF_TERM + " TEXT," + TERM_START_DATE + " TEXT,"
            + TERM_END_DATE + " TEXT" + ")";

    //Create course table
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_COURSE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + COURSE_TABLE + " (" + COURSE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + COURSE_NAME + " TEXT," + COURSE_START + " TEXT,"
            + COURSE_END + " TEXT," + COURSE_STATUS + " TEXT," + COURSE_MENTOR + " TEXT"
            + KEY_ID +"INTEGER FOREIGN KEY" + ")";


    public DBOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        //create all 4 tables
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TERMS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_COURSE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        //upgrade all 4 tables
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TERMS_TABLE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + COURSE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }
}
```

DataSource:

```
package com.mikero.termtracker;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DataSource {

    //Fields
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private DBOpenHelper helper;

    private String[] allTermColums = {DBOpenHelper.KEY_ID, DBOpenHelper.NAME_OF_TERM,
        DBOpenHelper.TERM_START_DATE, DBOpenHelper.TERM_END_DATE};

    private String[] allCourseColums = {DBOpenHelper.COURSE_ID, DBOpenHelper.COURSE_NAME,
        DBOpenHelper.COURSE_START, DBOpenHelper.COURSE_END, DBOpenHelper.COURSE_STATUS,
        DBOpenHelper.COURSE_MENTOR, DBOpenHelper.KEY_ID};

    public DataSource(Context context){
        helper = new DBOpenHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLiteException{
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close(){
        helper.close();
    }

    //Create Term
    public Term createTerm(Term term){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.NAME_OF_TERM, term.getTermsName());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.TERM_START_DATE, term.getTermStartDate());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.TERM_END_DATE, term.getTermEndDate());
        long insertId = db.insert(DBOpenHelper.TERMS_TABLE, null, cv);
        term.setId(insertId);
        return term;
    }

    //Create Course
    public Course createCourse(Course course){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_NAME, course.getCourseName());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_START, course.getCourseStart());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_END, course.getCourseEnd());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_STATUS, course.getCourseStatus());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_MENTOR, course.getCourseMentor());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.KEY_ID, course.getTermId());
        long insertId = db.insert(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_TABLE, null, cv);
        course.setId(insertId);
        return course;
    }

    //Update term
    public void updateTerm(Term term){
        long id = term.getId();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.NAME_OF_TERM, term.getTermsName());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.TERM_START_DATE, term.getTermStartDate());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.TERM_END_DATE, term.getTermEndDate());
        db.update(DBOpenHelper.TERMS_TABLE, cv, DBOpenHelper.KEY_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }

    //Update Course
    public void updateCourse(Course course){
        long id = course.getId();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_NAME, course.getCourseName());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_START, course.getCourseStart());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_END, course.getCourseEnd());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_STATUS, course.getCourseStatus());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_MENTOR, course.getCourseMentor());
        cv.put(DBOpenHelper.KEY_ID, course.getTermId());
        db.update(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_TABLE, cv, DBOpenHelper.COURSE_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }

    //CursorToTerm method
    private Term cursorToTerm(Cursor cursor){
        Term term  = new Term();
        term.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        term.setTermsName(cursor.getString(1));
        term.setTermStartDate(cursor.getString(2));
        term.setTermEndDate(cursor.getString(3));
        return term;
    }

    //CursorToCourse
    private Course cursorToCourse(Cursor cursor){
        Course course = new Course();
        course.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        course.setCourseName(cursor.getString(1));
        course.setCourseStart(cursor.getString(2));
        course.setCourseEnd(cursor.getString(3));
        course.setCourseStatus(cursor.getString(4));
        course.setCourseMentor(cursor.getString(5));
        return course;
    }

    //Getting all terms
    public List<Term> getAllTerms(){
        List<Term> termList = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(DBOpenHelper.TERMS_TABLE, allTermColums,
                null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Term term = cursorToTerm(cursor);
            termList.add(term);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return termList;
    }

    //Getting all courses
    public List<Course> getAllCourses(){
        List<Course> courseList = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_TABLE, allCourseColums,
                null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            Course course = cursorToCourse(cursor);
            courseList.add(course);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return courseList;
    }

    //Getting and creating a single term
    public Term getSingleTermById(long id){
        Cursor cursor = db.query(DBOpenHelper.TERMS_TABLE, allTermColums,
                DBOpenHelper.KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        Term term = cursorToTerm(cursor);
        return term;
    }

    //Getting and creating a single course
    public Course getSingleCourseById(long id){
        Cursor cursor = db.query(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_TABLE, allCourseColums,
                DBOpenHelper.COURSE_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }

       Course course = cursorToCourse(cursor);
        return course;
    }


    //Delete single term
    public void deleteTerm(Term term){
        long id = term.getId();
        db.delete(DBOpenHelper.TERMS_TABLE, DBOpenHelper.KEY_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }
    //Delete single course
    public void deleteCourse(Course course){
        long id = course.getId();
        db.delete(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_TABLE, DBOpenHelper.COURSE_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }

    //Delete single term by id
    public void deleteTermById(long id){
        db.delete(DBOpenHelper.TERMS_TABLE, DBOpenHelper.KEY_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }
    //Delete single course by id
    public void deleteCourseById(long id){
        db.delete(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_TABLE, DBOpenHelper.COURSE_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }

}
```

The activity causing problems:

```
package com.mikero.termtracker;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.List;

public class CourseActivity extends ListActivity {

    private DataSource ds;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_course);


        ds = new DataSource(this);
        ds.open();

        setAdapter();

    }
    @Override
    public void onRestart(){
        super.onRestart();
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());

    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        ArrayAdapter<Course> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Course>)getListAdapter();
        Course course = null;
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.addButtonCourse:
                final long termNo = (long) getIntent().getExtras().get(TermViewActivity.EXTRA_TERMNO);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CourseEditActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(TermViewActivity.EXTRA_TERMNO, termNo);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView listView,
                                View itemView,
                                int position,
                                long id){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CourseViewActivity.class);
        Course course = (Course)getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
        long itemId = course.getId();
        final long termNo = (long) getIntent().getExtras().get(TermViewActivity.EXTRA_TERMNO);
        intent.putExtra(TermViewActivity.EXTRA_TERMNO, termNo);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public ArrayAdapter<Course> setAdapter(){
        List<Course> courseList = ds.getAllCourses();
        ArrayAdapter<Course> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Course>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, courseList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        return adapter;
    }

}
```

The error report:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.mikero.termtracker, PID: 4304
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mikero.termtracker/com.mikero.termtracker.CourseActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: termId (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT courseId, courseName, courseStart, courseEnd, courseStatus, courseMentor, termId FROM course
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                   Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: termId (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT courseId, courseName, courseStart, courseEnd, courseStatus, courseMentor, termId FROM course
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1318)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1165)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1036)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1204)
                      at com.mikero.termtracker.DataSource.getAllCourses(DataSource.java:128)
                      at com.mikero.termtracker.CourseActivity.setAdapter(CourseActivity.java:67)
                      at com.mikero.termtracker.CourseActivity.onCreate(CourseActivity.java:28)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
Application terminated.
```

Thanks so much for taking the time to help :D

Comment: @Rotwang just clearing the data on my app isn't working.  I think it has something to do with the id's not being named _id

Comment: @Rotwang you are my hero.  That totally fixed everything.  I have a question for you, maybe this isn't the best spot to ask but, hey why not.  I'm finding that there are so many little idiosyncrasies with android like this one.  I'm also finding that books and the google developer site doesn't address all these small problems well.  How in the world have you been able to learn all the details of android?

Comment: Glad to help. I'm still learning, day by day. My googling skills are quite good. And mostly my searches bring back to here. Then I try and retry. I also have a solid development background since 1984. And a great imagination, too. So, I can possibly explore several alternative ways to do the same thing.